# Translate a DNA sequence into its aminoacids in Python

Tags: python

I'm stuck in a exercice in python where I need to convert a DNA sequence into its corresponding amino acids. So far, I have:

```
seq1 = "AATAGGCATAACTTCCTGTTCTGAACAGTTTGA"

for i in range(0, len(seq), 3):
    print seq[i:i+3]
```

I need to do this without using dictionaries, and I was going for replace, but it seems it's not advisable either. How can I achieve this?

And it's supposed to give something like this, for exemple:

```
>seq1_1_+
TQSLIVHLIY
>seq1_2_+
LNRSFTDSST
>seq1_3_+
SIADRSLTHLL
```

Update 2: OK, so i had to resort to functions, and as suggested, i have gotten the output i wanted. Now, i have a series of functions, which return a series of aminoacid sequences, and i want to get an output file that looks like this, for exemple:

```
>seq1_1_+
iyyslrs-las-smrlssiv-m
>seq1_2_+
fiirydrs-ladrcgshrssk
>seq1_3_+
llfativas-lidaalidrl
>seq1_1_-
frrsmraasis-lativannkm
>seq1_2_-
lddr-ephrsas-lrs-riin
>seq1_3_-
-tidesridqlasydrse--m
```

For that, i'm using this:

```
for x in f1:
    x = x.strip()
    if x.count("seq"):
        f2.write((x)+("_1_+\n"))
        f2.write((x)+("_2_+\n"))
        f2.write((x)+("_3_+\n"))
        f2.write((x)+("_1_-\n"))
        f2.write((x)+("_2_-\n"))
        f2.write((x)+("_3_-\n"))
    else:
        f2.write((translate1(x))+("\n"))
        f2.write((translate2(x))+("\n"))
        f2.write((translate3(x))+("\n"))
        f2.write((translate1neg(x))+("\n"))
        f2.write((translate2neg(x))+("\n"))
        f2.write((translate3neg(x))+("\n"))
```

But unlike the expected output file suggested, i get this:

```
>seq1_1_+
>seq1_2_+
>seq1_3_+
>seq1_1_-
>seq1_2_-
>seq1_3_-
iyyslrs-las-smrlssiv-m
fiirydrs-ladrcgshrssk
llfativas-lidaalidrl
frrsmraasis-lativannkm
lddr-ephrsas-lrs-riin
-tidesridqlasydrse--m
```

So he's pretty much doing all the seq's first, and all the functions afterwards, so i need to intercalate them, problem is how.

Comment: What is the problem with what you already have? It seems to give sensible results: "AAT", "AGG", ...

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: The title made me want to close this thread, but the question is not that bad. Still you need to take the advice from the other users and update the question if you want help.

Comment: i have the nucleotides, but now i need to convert them into it's corresponding aminoacids: N for AAT, R for AGG, ...

Comment: Do nucleotides and aminoacids have a 1-to-1 relation? How many such pairs are there?

Comment: 3 nucleotides to 1 aminoacid, and there are 20 aminoacids, from 64 possible combinations

Comment: Note that if it must have some biological meaning from DNA to protein there is the mRNA preprocess... ;)

Comment: If the problem is JUST the multiline, put a trailing comma after the `print`statement (python 2.X): `print aa,`

Answer (score 2):

To translate you need a table of [codons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_codon_table), so without dictionary or other data structure seems strange.

Maybe you can look into [biopython](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#sec26)? And see how they manage it.

You can also translate directly from the coding strand DNA sequence:

```
>>> from Bio.Seq import Seq
>>> from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC
>>> coding_dna = Seq("ATGGCCATTGTAATGGGCCGCTGAAAGGGTGCCCGATAG", IUPAC.unambiguous_dna)
>>> coding_dna
Seq('ATGGCCATTGTAATGGGCCGCTGAAAGGGTGCCCGATAG', IUPACUnambiguousDNA())
>>> coding_dna.translate()
Seq('MAIVMGR*KGAR*', HasStopCodon(IUPACProtein(), '*')) "
```

You may take a look [into](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/f0658115607dacb602de58e2438021d46d3c433b/Tests/test_Seq_objs.py)

Comment: Ops, thought you couldn't use functions... Create one empty string and instead of returning the result of if, append to string. In the end return the string.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot practically do this without either a function or a dictionary. Part 1, converting the sequence into three-character codons, is easy enough as you have already done it.

But Part 2, to convert these into amino acids, you will need to define a mapping, either:

```
mapping = {"NNN": "X", ...}
```

or

```
def mapping(codon):
    if codon in ("AGA", "AGG", "CGA", "CGC", "CGG", "CGT"):
        return "R"
    ...
```

or

```
for codon, acid in [("CAA", "Q"),  ("CAG", "Q"), ...]:
```

I would favour the second of these as it has the least duplication (and therefore potential for error).

Comment: Good suggestion, going to try this one and i'll let you know

Answer (score 1):

You got the amino acid output for the first codon only because you used 'return' inside the 'for loop'. Once the first amino acid is returned, the loop terminates, hence the second codon won't be tested at all.

You can create an empty list to keep the results for the translation of each codon, e.g.

```
aa = []
```

then, instead of using return, append the output to the list:

```
for x in range(0,len(seq1),3):
    nuc2= seq1[x:x+3]
    if nuc2 in ('GCT', 'GCC', 'GCA', 'GCG'):
        aa.append("a")
    elif nuc2 in ('TGT', 'TGC'):
        aa.append("c")
    ....
```

and finally, join the alphabets in the list and return the string from the function:

```
return "".join(aa)
```

or simply print it:

```
print("".join(aa))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the nucleotide bases in numbers (base 4) and then translate using ordered aa in a string:

```
def translate(seq,frame):
    BASES = 'ACGT'
    # standard code
    AA = 'KNKNTTTTRSRSIIMIQHQHPPPPRRRRLLLLEDEDAAAAGGGGVVVV*Y*YSSSS*CWCLFLF'
    # convert DNA sequence in numbers: A=0; C=1; G=2; T=3
    seqn = [str(BASES.index(i)) for i in seq.upper()]
    # list of all codons in all forward frames (i.e. 3 digit numbers in base 4)
    allframes = [''.join(seqn[x:x+3]) for x in range(len(seqn)) if x <= (len(seqn)-3)]
    # translate codons in frame taking aa in AA string using indexes (turned in base 10 from base 4) in allframes
    return ''.join([AA[int(i,4)] for i in allframes[(frame-1)::3]])
```